# Incompatibility when launching app between firebase and firebasecore

Tags: swift, firebase, carthage, xcodegen

While migrating from CocoaPods to Carthage our Firebase implementation I'm getting the following error:

```
This app could not be installed at this time.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Could not install at this time.
Recovery Suggestion: Found bundle at XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6858FE7A-714D-4A5E-A89C-AA487F5B21B6/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gLzACY/extracted/YYY/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework with the same identifier (com.firebase.Firebase) as bundle at XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6858FE7A-714D-4A5E-A89C-AA487F5B21B6/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gLzACY/extracted/YYY/Frameworks/Firebase.framework

Found bundle at XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6858FE7A-714D-4A5E-A89C-AA487F5B21B6/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gLzACY/extracted/YYY/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework with the same identifier (com.firebase.Firebase) as bundle at XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6858FE7A-714D-4A5E-A89C-AA487F5B21B6/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.gLzACY/extracted/YYY/Frameworks/Firebase.framework
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 57
User Info: {
FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundle performPreflightWithError:]";
LegacyErrorString = DuplicateIdentifier;
SourceFileLine = 391;
}
```

The original CocoaPods:

```
  target 'ZZZ' do
    pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 6.1'
  end
```

My Cartfile for this migration:

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseDatabaseBinary.json" == 6.1.0
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json" == 6.1.0
```

Through my code we are importing "Firebase" and "FirebaseDatabase"

Embedding these resulting frameworks through xcodegen:

```
  - carthage: FirebaseDatabase
  - carthage: FirebaseAnalytics
  - carthage: leveldb-library
  - carthage: Firebase
  - carthage: GoogleUtilities
  - carthage: FirebaseCore
```

I have tried going for ~> on my cartfile but the same problem happens.
I have tried not embedding FirebaseCore and the compilation fails due to missing Firebase classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you completed the step from the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md)?

> Delete Firebase.framework from the Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase.